# db.database.ExecuteSQLCommand equivalent in EF 7

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Whats the equivalent of

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Sql.ToString());
```

in Entity Framework 7? I saw .FromSQL() in beta 4, but haven't seen anything to the above.

Comment: **Update** - Currently, `ExecuteSQLCommand` can be used in Entity Framework Core. However, you need to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature isn't implemented yet. Track its progress using issue [#624](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/624). Here is a crude extension method you can use for now.

```
public static int ExecuteSqlCommand(this RelationalDatabase database, string sql)
{
    var connection = database.Connection;
    var command = connection .DbConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sql;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
db.Database.AsRelational().ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC MySproc");
```

Note, this doesn't take into account any active transaction.

Comment: I'll create an extension on DbContext that read out the connectionstring and generates a seperate SqlConnection with SqlCommand. Perhaps that would be my "temporarily" fix then :)

Comment: You should use "using" though and drop the try catch... You won't know that anything goes wrong here. Accepted your answer. Any reason why you extend RelationalDatabase? I extended DbContext so you could use like db.executeSql("SQL QUERY"); ( just started using Asp.Net 5 so, so enlight me ^^ )

Comment: Updated the code, i really hate try catches because it hides errors :)

Comment: It won't hide errors--there's no catch. It just ensures the connection gets closed if there are errors.

Comment: Also, DbCommand wasn't intended to be disposed. The Dispose method is an unfortunate result of deriving from Component.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to provide an update of the latest way to use this with for Entity Framework Core RC1.

There is an extentsion on the **DatabaseFacade** class in the **Microsoft.Data.Entity** namespace that you can use as follows:

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC MySproc");
```

Comment: This has been moved to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace in RTM